# Convincing project lead to use asp.net forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

We are implementing security for our application. The project lead has already decided that he wants us to role are own, but as the lead developer, I don't want to go down that road when my time should be spent implementing things relevent to the business.

Our security requirements are very simple, no permissions, just roles. I do not see any reason to waste my time implementing a custom solution.

Are there any articles or case studies someone could point me to that I could use as a justification for not rolling my own security?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Lol Brandon, not now, just bought a house.

Comment: also, I am pretty sure management will side with me, I just need supporting documents... you know... politics.

Comment: Common sense should tell you to not roll your own, especially where security is concerned. Further, Microsoft has had over a decade to fix any forms authentication bugs, so why write your own bugs?

Comment: You are preeching to the choir John, just need some supporting evidence... project lead has a Database background... he doesn't like how many tables there are and how they are named.

Comment: @NotCodingCoder My first comment was a joke... but after hearing his "justification", I actually think it's pretty solid advice...

Comment: ASP.NET security has three parts to it: authentication (session cookie), membership (account id/pass), authorization (roles). The last two require database to store the data. If your DBA lead wants to control the schema, you can still use forms auth for the session management and implement membership/roles interfaces with your own providers and data.

Answer (score 1):

You can always implement your 'own' solution by deriving from the built-in classes. This way all the configuration will be pointing to your custom code but it will only contain the derivations from the standard, not everything.

Comment: Yes, you can use this approach to clean up the database schema. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

Comment: I am aware, and was planning on going this route if forced to roll my own... but still, the main issue is the time I will lose building this thing!

Comment: See also: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/06/01/create-a-flexible-security-system.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, "rolling your own" security is not only unwise, but reckless.  Enumerating even a miniscule percentage of security fails as a result of roll-your-own would be impossible, but if you need ammo for this, point out the massive number of "lessons learned" in these books.  (These are excellent web security books by the way).  These books are *teeming* with massive hacks that resulted from small oversights by security implementers.  Why repeat history?

1. [The Tangled Web](http://nostarch.com/tangledweb)
2. [Web Application Hacker's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026470)
3. [Web Application Defender's Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118362187)

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking more a long the lines of a microsoft article warning why not to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the default is the lowest risk and the best fit 99% of the time. For completeness sake (here be dragons!), the rest of the story:

[ASP.NET Forms Authentication Considered Broken](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/22/asp-net-forms-authentication-considered-broken) (2012-02-22)

[The ASP.NET Forms Authentication replacement Microsoft doesn't want you to see](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/08/13/the-asp-net-forms-authentication-replacement-microsoft-doesn-t-want-you-to-see) (2012-08-13)

- "the forms authentication cookie payload format changes semi-frequently with .NET updates and that causes problems for application maintainers"
- "Having multiple alternative authentication solutions means that a weakness discovered in one of them won't let an attacker bring down all ASP.NET sites on the web"

  - ['Padding Oracle' Crypto Attack Affects Millions of ASP.NET Apps](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1687547) (2010-09-13)
- "The way Forms Authentication is baked into the .NET Framework also poses some challenges"

This is the big one for me:

- "standard Forms Authentication tends to saddle unwary developers with poor application design"

Comment: I wish my rep was high enough to downvote this dribble. Who the heck is stupid enough to put sensitive info into a cookie anyway?